# Select correct element to be shown

Tags: javascript

So I have the below code that I wish to change but I am unsure on the direction I need to go with this other than I need to use Javascript. Ideally I would like to click the button (id="popupbtn") so show the corresponding 'MainDescription' panel. The issue I have is that I have all of this in a loop so how do I go about making each button display the maindescription it is connected to?

I hope it makes sense because I'm spent awhile trying to figure out how to explain the I am having!

```
!--Quick Details-->
<h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $forsale['make'];?> <?php echo $forsale['model'];?> <?php echo $forsale['variant'];?></h4>
<h4>Price: £<?php echo $forsale['price'];?></h4>
<input type="hidden" id="stockbox" value="<?php echo $forsale['StockID'];?>">
<p id="stockref" class="form-control">Stock Ref: <?php echo $forsale['StockID'] ?></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-md form-control" id="popupbtn" onclick="MainDescription()">View More</button>

<div class="maindescription" id="maindesc" value="<?php echo $forsale['StockID'];?>" style="display:none">
    <p id="descYear" class="form-control">Year: <?php echo $forsale['year'] ?></p>
    <p id="descmileage" class="form-control">Mileage: <?php echo $forsale['mileage'] ?></p>
    <p id="descFuel" class="form-control">Fuel: <?php echo $forsale['fuel'] ?></p>
    <p id="descDoors" class="form-control">No. Doors: <?php echo $forsale['doors'] ?></p>
    <p id="descTrans" class="form-control">Transmission: <?php echo $forsale['trans'] ?></p>
    <p id="descEnginesize" class="form-control">Engine Size: <?php echo $forsale['enginesize'] ?></p>
    <p id="description" class="form-control">Description: <?php echo $forsale['description'] ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Look up javascript accordion

Comment: @Mattex if you have the example code in a loop, if you are using a for(let x = 0; x < something; x++) kind of loop, you could use x as an index and append that to the id value of the button and the div, then when you click the button retrieve the index off of the id and use that to determine which div to unhide.

Comment: @RyanWilson I have add the $x value to set up the button value and the panel value, how do I go about finding both of the same values?

Comment: Change the onclick of your button from this: onclick="MainDescription(), to this: onclick="MainDescription(this.id)", then change your function from MainDescription() to onclick="MainDescription(id), then parse out the index from your id being passed into MainDescription()

Comment: @RyanWilson Sorry dude but I dont do much of JavaScript and my head is just *explodes* heres the code I changed out
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-md form-control" id="<?php $x;?>" onclick="MainDescription(this.id)">View More</button>

         <div class="maindescription" id="<?php echo $x;?>" style="display:none">
          <p id="descYear" class="form-control">Year: <?php echo $forsale['year'] ?></p>
          <p id="descmileage" class="form-control">Mileage: <?php echo $forsale['mileage'] ?></p>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this at the end of the HTML document to do that:

```
<script>
function MainDescription() {
  const panel = document.getElementById('maindesc');
  if (panel.style.display === 'none') {
    panel.style.display = 'block'
  } else {
    panel.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have this currently but click any of the three view more buttons opens the first panels main description not the say if I click on no.3 and it opens no.,3 main description

Comment: Check what the function is doing and you can adapt it to show/hide any part of your UI. Remember the `id`s must be unique or you will be targeting only the first one.